# Unable to view an account balance using monerojs

Tags: transaction-data, testnet, javascript

I downloaded my local node on the ***Monero testnet***, specifically I used:

> **monerod --testnet --db-sync-mode fast --prune-blockchain**

After successfully launching the node, I mined some *XMR*. My intention is to test Monero ***transactions*** with the ***monerojs Javascript library***.

Currently on my Monero address I have about 1.5 XMR but when I try to view my balance from the local Javascript console, it always shows me a balance equal to zero.

This is the Javascript code I used:

```
let wallet = await monerojs.createWalletFull({
    networkType: MoneroNetworkType.TESTNET,
    password: "<MyPass>",
    mnemonic: "<myMnemonic>",
    server: new monerojs.MoneroRpcConnection("http://127.0.0.1:28081"),
    });

const syncResult = await wallet.sync();
console.log('Sync progress:', syncResult);

let account= await wallet.getAccount(0)
  const balance=account.getBalance() // or const balance=parseInt(account.getBalance().toString(), 10)
  console.log("BALANCE:")
  console.log(balance)

//RETURN ME THIS:
BALANCEE
BigInteger { _d: [], _s: 0 }

or

BALANCEE
0
```

Can someone explain to me if I'm doing the wrong connection to the daemon or some wallet configuration?

Comment: Have you fully synced/scanned the blockchain with your wallet? Your post above doesn't show you have actually done this. See example usage in the tests: [src/test/TestMoneroWalletFull.js](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/blob/1dd867020173cc0eebf4c8d962dd45d1a59965d3/src/test/TestMoneroWalletFull.js)

Comment: I was doing the sync function wrong at the node. Now works. The only thing is that it is very slow to sync the wallet. If I do it via monero-wallet-cli it's much faster